# Multiplying binary rasters

Tags: qgis, raster, buffer, raster-calculator, binary

I have 2 binary rasters: one of them contains buffer zones around evacuation roads and the other one contains buffer zones around rivers. I want to find out the areas located near the evacuation roads and far away from the rivers. For this purpose, I have set "0" and "1" values to the required zones for both of the rasters. I thought that by multiplying respective rasters in the calculator, I would be able to find wanted areas. But unfortunately, the result from the calculator does not come out as a binary raster (the expression that I wrote is "Rasterized_rivers@1" * "Rasterized_roads@1").
How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: What does the result come out like? How wrong is it?

Comment: @Spacedman thanks for answering, it is showing a band range of -340 and 340 as a default I think and I can not see anything while changing symbology(labeling "0" and "1" values).hope that my answer is clear

Comment: Have you tried adding the rasters together instead? Any 2's would be your desired areas in the result. Worth a try.

Comment: @lambertj  thanks for answering!i have tried it right now, but it gives the same result(

Comment: It sounds like somehow your rasters are categorical with different values being shown as 0 and 1. Does the output raster seem to have the right pattern, even though it has the wrong values? Or does it bear no relation to the zeros and ones of the input?

Comment: @Spacedman unfortunately, the output raster is a blank page.i think that, maybe i should do some changes in the raster calculator menu so it can take the 0 and 1 values from the maps respectively?

Comment: I don't know, can't really tell without your data, but if your data really are 0 and 1 then what you do should be correct. Check and double check that your rasters really are 0 and 1, check their metadata and their info and their histograms and click on them with the query tool and see what values come back.